Getting Empty response for the cheque I uploaded in Zia Identity Scanner In Zoho Catalyst Console
I wanted to get the account details from the cheque I uploaded in Zia Identity Scanner from Zoho catalyst console. But I am getting 200 response with empty response. Can someone help me identify the issue?
This is the response I am getting:
    {
    "status": 200,
    "content": {},
    "message": "OK"
}


You might have faced this issue if you have uploaded a non CTS-2010 compliant cheque. Catalyst Zia Services only supports cheques that are CTS-2010 compliant. You can refer to their official help documentation here.
CTS-2010 Compliant referes to cheque that follows the The Cheque Truncation System (CTS) is a clearance system used by the Reserve Bank of India (RBI) to process cheques more quickly. You can refer to the official RBI document here.
